# Limit of infinity

Tags: limits

Suppose that you have a function $f(x,y) $ and you're interested in calculating the limit $ \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y'} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x'} f(x,y)$, where $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x'}f(x,y)=\infty $. Then, is the limit $ \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y'} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x'} f(x,y)=\infty$ as well or not defined? In other words, does $ \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow y'}\infty$ make sense?

Comment: Assuming $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, do you have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x'}f(x,y)=\infty$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$, or just for some specific $y \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: The first definitions of limits allowing infinite limits you would see only consider real-valued sequences. You can however topologize $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ so that the limit of $\infty$ is $\infty$ and $-\infty$, $-\infty$, as well as all previously defined limits. But sequences converging to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ with some terms replaced by $\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively are the only new convergent sequences you get, so it could be preferable to just add these limits to the definition of a limit, and avoid the more complex unifying definition.